# Fill cell value with formatted date returned from function

Tags: excel, vba, date

I have tried every approach that I know but I haven't been able to set the cell value with its date. I suspect there is a tiny problem, but I don't know where.

```
Function getDates(strDateString) As Date
Dim x As Variant
x = Split(strDateString, "/")
If UBound(x) = 2 Then
    strday = x(2)
    strMonth = x(1)
    strYear = x(0)
Else
    strYear = Mid(strDateString, 1, 4)
    strMonth = Mid(strDateString, 6, 2)
    strday = Mid(strDateString, 8, 2)
End If

getDates = DateSerial(strYear, strMonth, strday)
End Function

For k = 11 To 12
    strdates = getDates(Cells(2, k).Value)
    Set Worksheets(strNewSheetName).Range(Cells(1, k), Cells(1, k)).Value = CStr(strdates)
    MsgBox (strdates)
Next k
```

`MsgBox` will return the correct date, but the value always remains empty!  I tried converting it to a string with each of these methods:

```
cells(r,c).value
CSTR(strDates)
cdate()
```

But none of these worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
Set Worksheets(strNewSheetName).Range(Cells(1, k), Cells(1, k)).Value = CStr(strdates)
```

to

```
Worksheets(strNewSheetName).Cells(1, k).Value = CStr(strdates)
```

`Set` is used to set the value of an object but you're not dealing with an object when setting a cell value. Furthermore, defining a range from one cell to itself is also redundant.

Comment: I tried it with set, without set, always the value is empty!

Comment: In my tests if I have 'Set' there I get a 'run time error object required' error.  Can you show more of your code?  What you've got there won't compile on it's own.  The loop is outside of any sort of function